# Using fnmatch to match 2 parts of a file name

Tags: python, regex

I am currently using `fnmatch` to find the files that I want to copy and to ignore the rest:

Below is some of my script just to give an example of how it's used.

```
pattern = "*.xlsx"

if fnmatch(name, pattern):
    source_files.append(os.path.join(path, name))
```

What I've realised is that this is currently also matching hidden files, which I don't want copied.

I see 3 options for solving this problem:

1. I could either exclude hidden files as a whole.
2. I could exclude files that begin with `~$`.
3. Or I could only choose files that begin with `Update` *and* end with `.xlsx`

I feel that the easiest way to describe the type of files I want to copy is with regex but I don't think fnmatch accepts full regex.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fnmatch`'s ability to exclude certain characters, also specified in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html)

```
In [33]: fnmatch('hello.xlsx', '[!~]*.xlsx')
Out[33]: True

In [34]: fnmatch('~hello.xlsx', '[!~]*.xlsx')
Out[34]: False
```

And as for the last comment in your question - if you feel the best way to describe your file is with regex, why not replace `fnmatch` with `re.match(...) is not None`? Do you have to use `fnmatch`?

Comment: The reason for using `fnmatch` was because it was what was recommended to me. I am new to python, especially using it for doing operations with files like this. So file matching and regex is something I've never done. Hence my lack of understanding with matching functions. Thanks for your help, worked like a charm!